# Problem on direct sum

Tags: linear-algebra

> Consider subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$: $L_1, L_2, L_3$ with dimensions
>   $n_1, n_2, n_3$, respectively. It's known that $n_1 + n_2 + n_3 = n$
>   and $L_1 + L_2 + L_3 = \mathbb{R}^n$.
>
> Prove that sum $L_1 + L_2$ is direct.

The only thing I see is that the sums $L_1 \oplus (L_2 + L_3), L_3 \oplus (L_2 + L_1), L_2 \oplus (L_1 + L_3)$ are direct. Please give me a hint how to prove.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is not direct then its dimension is less than n_1+n_2 giving the total dimension less than n_1+n_2+n_3=n and so the three spaces stop to generate rhe whole space R^n.